# How to combine two stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using stored procedure to get the result.

My requirement is to combine two sp result into one table.

First stored procedure is:

```
EXEC spDisplayBankConsolidate 'pname',@yr=2013
```

which returns these results :

```
Bankcode        Amt
Cash        13867.00
Csb         21598.50
Fd         700990.00
```

The second stored procedure is called like this:

```
EXEC spDisplayBankConsolidate 'pname', @yr=2013, @equal='Eq'`
```

Results:

```
Bankcode        Amt
Cash        13867.00
Csb          5598.50
Fd        1138049.00
```

My requirement is to combine the result as follows

```
Bankcode    Opening        Closing
Cash         13867.00        13867.00
Csb          21598.50         5598.50
Fd          700990.00      1138049.00
```

Comment: What type of SQL are you using? MySQL? SQL Server?

Comment: Insert results into tmp tables and then join them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two temporary tables (or table variables), insert into those, then join them based on the common field (`Bankcode`)

Like this, I think:

```
create table #TableOne (BankCode nvarchar, Amt money)
create table #TableTwo (BankCode nvarchar, Amt money)

INSERT INTO #TableOne EXEC spDisplayBankConsolidate 'pname',@yr=2013
INSERT INTO #TableOne EXEC spDisplayBankConsolidate 'pname',@yr=2013,@equal='Eq'

select
    t1.BankCode, 
    t1.Amt as Opening, 
    t2.Amt as Closing
from #TableOne t1
inner join #TableTwo t2 on t1.BankCode = t2.BankCode
```

I made this based on the answer to this question: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d400a970-e0db-4324-9e99-9dfba214a55a/store-output-of-sql-server-exec-into-a-table?forum=transactsql

Comment: I am getting this error
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Procedure spDisplayBankConsolidate, Line 6
String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: Oh yeah, you'll need to probably specify a larger `nvarchar` depending on your source columns. I mean, `(BankCode nvarchar(max)...` will work, but you probably want to get it right